# what is the regular expression for identifying decimal number

Tags: python, regex

I have tried writing a code for identifying decimal number in python using regular expression as indicated in the below code.

It is working fine for many case but still failing to identify below inputs

```
import re
string = input()
r = re.compile(r"([+\-.]?\d*\.\d+)\b")
if(r.match(string)):
    print(True)
else: 
    print(False)
```

234.2344  ->for this input giving expected results

+.3456468 ->for this input giving expected results

5.34.0  -> for this input it should print False

4+345.0  -> for this input it should print False

Comment: `^[+-]\d+(\.\d+)$`  try this

Comment: You should add `^` at the start and `$` at the end. Without it, as long as the string **contains** a valid decimal pattern it will accept. You want to force it to capture the whole string

Comment: Also, just do `float(string)`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo: I have tried but it is not showing matching the decimal numbers. see below link 

https://regexr.com/4he9t

Answer (score 4):

These expressions might likely validate integer and decimal numbers:

```
^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$
```

or

```
^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$
```

if for instance `1.` would be valid.

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/SQ3huw/1/)

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/mrDgTP/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$"

test_str = ("0.00000\n"
    "0.00\n"
    "-100\n"
    "+100\n"
    "-100.1\n"
    "+100.1\n"
    ".000\n"
    ".1\n"
    "3.\n"
    "4.")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE))
```

#### Output

```
['0.00000', '0.00', '-100', '+100', '-100.1', '+100.1', '.000', '.1']
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mrDgTP/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^[+-]?(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

[image]

[`Python demo`](https://regex101.com/r/xNl00A/3/codegen?language=python)|[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/xNl00A/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use beginning `^` and end anchors `$` if you don't want it to match the first decimal-like part:

```py
import re
decimal_re = re.compile(r'^\D?[+-]?\d*\.?\d+$')

cases = [
    '234.2344',
    '+.3456468',
    '5.34.0',
    '4+345.0',
    '1.5555',
    '.123123',
    '456.',
    '4.4.5.5'
]
for c in cases:
    print(decimal_re.match(c))
```

output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='234.2344'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='+.3456468'>
None
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='1.5555'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='.123123'>
None
None
```